# Icon sets showing trend and number in same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

Know how to customize the icon set conditional formatting in excel? 
Basically check for next month & show up down or neutral values??
This has to be done for say next 18 months

Desired output - same cell say A3 should have the number for the month and relevant arrow key (when compared to A2)

or can this be done in VBA??

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are you always comparing to A2 or to the previous cell? Can you post a screenshot of some sample data, with at least 5 rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're always comparing to A2, then select the rest of the data, add Arrow Icon set as usual, then modify that conditional formatting:

1. Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules
2. Select the Icon Set and click Edit Rule
3. Then change the conditions to Formulas that compare to A2

[image]